# Где я ошибся в логическом выражении?

Tags: python

Вот само выражение - ((x ∈ P) ≡ (x ∈ Q)) → ¬(x ∈ A)

Вот мой код:

```
#Наибольшее -> remove
#Наименьшее -> append



p = list(range(5, 31))
q = list(range(14, 24))
a = list(range(52))

for x in range(52):
    if not(((x in p) == (x in q)) <= (x not in a)):
        a.remove(x)
print(a)
```

Вот сама задача, если кому надо:

На числовой прямой даны два отрезка: P = [5, 30] и Q = [14, 23]. Укажите наибольшую возможную длину промежутка A, для которого формула

((x ∈ P) ≡ (x ∈ Q)) → ¬(x ∈ A)

тождественно истинна, то есть принимает значение 1 при любом значении переменной х.

Вывод, который должен:
`[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]`

Мой вывод:
`[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]`

Comment: Почему вы считаете что ошибка в формуле? Кажется, вы не довели решение задачи до конца.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Что ты имеешь ввиду? Как не дорешал?

Comment: Вы не учли что точки есть и между целыми числами. Лучше бы вы на листке бумаги решали.

Comment: Словосочетание "открытый промежуток" ни о чем не говорит?

Comment: Длина промежутка не меняется в зависимости от его открытости. Длина любого промежутка - разность его концов. Это определение. (Я говорю о промежутках на множестве вещественных чисел, не целых).

Comment: Тут вы правы, но тогда другой вопрос, есть варианты, как это решить через пайтон? @StanislavVolodarskiy

Comment: Поставьте `sympy` - он умеет работать с промежутками на вещественной прямой.

Comment: Могли бы написать это в ответ, чтобы я закрыл вопрос? @StanislavVolodarskiy

Comment: Напишите самоответ. Это разрешено и это хорошо.

Comment: В вашем решении на бумажке скобки перепутаны.

Comment: По решению на бумажке получается ответ [5;14) и (23;30], но тогда почему мы должны вычетать 14- 5, если 14 не входит в эту точку, ведь это открытый с одной стороны промежуток. @StanislavVolodarskiy

Comment: Длина промежутка не меняется в зависимости от его открытости.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[sympy.Interval](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/sets.html#sympy.sets.sets.Interval) представляет отрезок прямой:

```
import sympy

p = sympy.Interval(5, 30)
q = sympy.Interval(14, 23)

r = p.symmetric_difference(q)
print(r)
```

> ```
> $ python symdif.py
> Union(Interval.Ropen(5, 14), Interval.Lopen(23, 30))
> ```